# SpriteKit: Setting scene background colour: Low FPS

Tags: sprite-kit

So I am super new to SpriteKit. What I am trying to do is set the background colour for my scene. So I do this

```
SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"nightback.png"];
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture size:view.frame.size];
background.zPosition = -1;
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:background];
```

and in my controller I do this

```
 GameScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width,skView.bounds.size.height)];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

So I try removing "setting the size of the scene" part from the code and it goes back to 60fps. Now the issue is the background node does not cover the whole screen.

Now

1. How do I set the background for a scene without having a 50% drop in fps?
2. Why does setting the size of a scene have such a huge effect?

Comment: Let me take a *wild* guess ... you're testing this on the Simulator, right?

Comment: Yes :) I think I know where this is going.

Comment: So I don't have to point out how the Simulator uses a very slow software renderer? Well then... :)

Comment: Note to self : Obvious reasons are obvious for a reason. Did that make sense? Anyways, Thank you sir for your assistance.